# How to ignore first line with php include?

Tags: php, include, command-line-interface, shebang, php-include

I have a php script, which can be run independently from the command line, so it's first line is `#!/usr/bin/env php`. However, I also have another script, which can automatically run the first one. It does this by calling `include 'example.php'`, which works, except that it outputs the first line as text.

How do I make include skip the first line? So far the only options I could think of were to wrap the whole thing in an output buffer and then trim the first line, but that has a whole host of problems with it. Alternatives such as using `exec()` to simulate running the second script from the command line, or reading in the whole file and evaluating it with `eval()`, both seem like pretty horrible solutions.

Is there any way to tell php, "include this file but don't output the first line"?

I am aware I can just remove the shebang and run the script with `php script.php` whenever I need to use it, which is ok in this specific case, but I would still like to know if there is an alternative, general way to make include ignore the first (or first X) lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO a script with a shebang is very explicitly a "front end" to the command line and should not be included in other scripts in the first place, because it contains code specific to dealing with CLI interaction (parsing passed arguments and such). It would probably make more sense to separate the reusable code in that script out into a library file, then include that file from both the shebang script and the other script.

I.e., instead of:

`foo.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
// some code
```

`bar.php`:

```
include 'foo.php';
```

you do:

`lib.php`:

```
// some code
```

`foo.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
include 'lib.php';
```

`bar.php`:

```
include 'lib.php';
```

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a weird case that brought this to mind - the calling script is actually doing some processing to decide which sub-script to call, and then activating it as if it was called directly, including all giving it all command line arguments/options, which of course are accessible to an included file as if it was called directly, alone.

Answer (score 2):

```
ob_start();
include $file;
$stdout = ob_get_contents(); // shebang line will be there
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Include/Require technicaly say, execute, no (extra) evaluation.

Your Solution should be the other way:

- PHP File
- Bashscript which execute PHP File.

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` is the right solution. But even better change your understanding of scripting.

Your command line executable is basicly a controller, which says what to execute. Your command line script might be as simple as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require_once('classes/DoThing.php');

array_shift($argv);
DoThing::run($argv);
```

Then you don't need to include or `exec()` the command line script, just use the class.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is comments tags:

In the included file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<!-- none -->    
<?php
 ...
```

In the main file:

```
<?php
 ...
 echo '<!-- ';
 include x.php;
 ...
```